# Ionic 4 | Text selection does not happen on iPad iOS 13.4

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, webview, ionic4

After updating an iPad to the latest version (13.4), selecting the text by holding and dragging is no longer working. we've tested it in 2 ionic 4 apps and in both, the text selection didn't work

**Issue:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12f-TX9VKKhXyt0hXb5bJCuKQhizGeZb0/view?usp=sharing

**Example:**

```html
<div class="selectable">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, se
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation laboris.
</div>
```

```css
.selectable {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

**Version information:**

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.10
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.10
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : 0.11.0
   native-run  : not installed

System:
   NodeJS : v12.14.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.2
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: text is not supported on all ios devices as the reference i send say, maybe use auto or i don't i send since it could help. Good luck.